# How to find out whether child widget of QScrollArea is visible?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qscrollarea

I am displaying multiple `QLabels` on a `QFrame`, placed into a `QScrollArea`.

I am able to tell `QScrollArea` to make any of the `QLabels` visible with `QScrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible(QLabel)`, but I cannot seem to find a method to find out whether the child widget is currently visible or not. I would expect something like `QScrollArea.isWidgetVisible(QWidget)`.

I tried using the child's own method, i.e. `QLabel.isVisible()` but no matter whether the `QLabel` is visible or not in the `QScrollArea`, it always returns `True` (see example below). What's the solution to this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore



application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Area(QtGui.QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, child):
            super(Area, self).__init__()
        self.child = child
        self.setWidget(self.child)
        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)


class MainWidget(QtGui.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        n = 1
        while n != 10:
            label = QtGui.QLabel('<h1>'+str(n)+'</h1>')
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
            n += 1
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        print "Wheel Event:"
        for child in self.children()[1:]:
            print child.isVisible()
        event.ignore()

mainwidget = MainWidget()
area = Area(mainwidget)
area.show()
application.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isVisible` is different from what you want to do. It tells whether the widget is hidden or not. Even though it is not in the viewport a widget is visible unless you `hide` it.

You could use `visibleRegion`. It is the region of the widget that paint events should occur. If the label is outside of the viewport, then it's region should be an empty region.

```
def wheelEvent(self, event):
    print "Wheel Event:"
    for child in self.children()[1:]:
        print child.text(), 'is visible?', not child.visibleRegion().isEmpty()
    event.ignore()
```

Answer (score 0):

[QScrollArea::ensureWidgetVisible](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#ensureWidgetVisible) would do.

You can use `QSCrollArea::childAt ( int x, int y ).isvisble()` for checking widget visibility.

Comment: QScrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible will merely move the widget so that it is visible. It won't tell me whether the widget was visible or not in the first place.

QScrollArea.childAt will merely return the widget at the given position and then QWidget.isVisible should return whether the widget is visible or not. That is not different from what I did in the code above, where I returned all children widgets, and which does not work, since it returns True for all widgets, even though they are not visible in the QScrollArea.